# C++ Create a vector from attributes of objects in another vector

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

Assuming I have a class `A` and a vector of instances `instances`

```cpp
class A {
public:
    int a;
}

std::vector<A> instances;  // Contains several A objects
```

I now want to create a vector of `int` from the attribute `a` of objects in `A`.

The naive way would be

```cpp
std::vector attributes;
for (auto& obj: instances) {
    attributes.push_back(obj.a);
}
```

Is there a way to do it in just one line? Something conceptually close to python's

```py
attributes = [obj.a for obj in instances]
```

Comment: [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)?

Comment: `std::vector<int> attributes; std::transform(instances.cbegin(), instances.cend(), std::back_inserter(attributes), [](auto const &e){return e.a;});`

Comment: With C++20, `std::ranges::transform(instances, std::back_inserter(attributes), &A::a)` using the projection argument, should work and be much more succinct than the old way.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

```
std::vector<...> attributes;
attributes.reserve(instances.size());
std::transform(instances.begin(), instances.end(), std::back_inserter(attributes),
               [](auto&& obj) { return obj.a; });
```

Comment: fwiw, thats the equivalent of OPs loop, though it would be more efficient to resize `attributes` upfront and drop the `back_inserter`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number resizing in advance would initialise all elements to `0` which could be slower, using `reserve` and keeping the `back_inserter` is likely to be more performant

Comment: @AlanBirtles oh right. The question getting closed saved me from posting a poor answer ;)